# Unable to set Background in Imagebutton

Tags: android, background, android-imagebutton

Here i have a `ImageButton`:

```
  <com.defcomdevs.invento16.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

SquareImageView is a class that extends the Imagebutton to basically set the width and height automatically according to the Screen size.

custom_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#885599"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="8dp" android:color="#802196f3"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="#802196f3" android:endColor="#802196f3"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**My Problem** is that when i set the background as custom_button the image that i set programmatically overlaps the entire area of the button.not showing the background.Otherwise the image perfectly sets inside the button.
Some thing like this:

[image]

As you can see this is the case with background=custom_button.

[image]

this is the case otherwise.
Now i don't want any of these.
**What i want is** that the custom_button is set as the background of the ImageButton and the src as that image as shown.How to da that??Please help.Thanks.

`SquareImageView.class`:

```
package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageButton {

public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}
}
```

Comment: You want the background to be this custom drawable with the state list for when a user presses it, and the src to be the images, but without the border like in your second images you showed?? So it should look like the first images but have the effects of the custom drawable states?? Is that what you want?

Comment: try: android:scaleType="fitXY". this should fill the button's maximum height and width with the src image while still having your background

Comment: @LucasCrawford No sir this didn't work.Thanks.But i have updated my question and have added the squareimageview class to it,maybe this is causing the problem..

Comment: Got it sir,added `android:padding="5dp"`,this correctly fit the image into my button.as the stroke has "5dp" width.Thanks.But still the image overlaps the background because of which the transparent color that i provided in my pressed state= true is not showing.